# Creating values

Tags: excel, formula

This is complex and I don't know how to get what I want. I can do it individually, but that defeats the purpose of the code I'm trying to figure out.

I want it to search through a given range, once it finds it's value, finds it's coinciding value however many rows over, adds them all up, then outputs the the first value and it's second value in coinciding cells. Maybe even into a different sheet.

If you understood what I typed, I applaud you, because I know that was probably confusing and/or you didn't understand. So I will try to clarify by posting screenshots of what I want (like I said, you can do it manually, but who wants to go through 100+ columns searching?)

Example:
[image: Example]

Whether there's one instance or 50, I'd like to add up the values.

Comment: You can use `SUMIF()` for this

Comment: or a pivot table - if there's many columns, you can add them all, and just look at the grand total

Answer (score 0):

In **D15** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **D16** enter the *array formula:*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D$15:D15,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D$15:D15,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1),1)),"")
```

and copy down. *(adjust the 1000 to meet your needs)*

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Then in **E15** enter:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$1000,D15,B:B)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution that will copy the summary to a new sheet.  Uses `.Sort` and `.Subtotal`. There is a "setup" section in the code for you to customise to your situation/requirements.

A couple of points:

You will need to insert a row at the top of your data and and add some column titles (these are required by the `.SubTotal` method).

You can either leave the subtotal format in the original data (may be useful for checking/auditing?) or remove them (see annotations in the code).

Both the data and the result summary will be left in alphabetical order.

Take care if you adjust the code to paste the summary into the original worksheet (the .SubTotal method hides rows!).

```
Option Explicit

Sub STot()
Dim dataws As Worksheet, destws As Worksheet
Dim drng As Range
Dim strow As Long, endrow As Long, stcol As Long, endcol As Long
Dim filtrows As Long, modcell As Long
Dim cpyrow As Long, cpycol As Long

'Setup ==========================
'data and destination worksheets
Set dataws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destws = Sheets("Sheet3")

'position of data on dataws
strow = 1
stcol = 1  'Col A

'cell position to copy - on new worksheet (destws)
cpyrow = 2
cpycol = 3
'End of setup ===================

    With dataws
        'find last data row/column
        endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, stcol).End(xlUp).Row
        endcol = Cells(stcol, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'sort data
        Set drng = .Range(.Cells(strow, stcol), .Cells(endrow, endcol))
        drng.Sort Key1:=.Cells(strow, stcol), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        'apply Excel SubTotal function
        drng.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=2

        'collapse Subtotal levels to show summary
        .Outline.ShowLevels 2

        ' copy results to another worksheet
        drng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destws.Cells(cpyrow, cpycol)

        'if you want to remove subtotals from original data
        .Cells.RemoveSubtotal
    End With

    'tidy-up output on destination worksheet
    With destws
        'remove headings
        .Cells(cpyrow, cpycol).Resize(2, 2).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        'remove "Total" string in each name
        Do While Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(cpyrow, cpycol).Value))
            .Cells(cpyrow, cpycol).Value = Left(.Cells(cpyrow, cpycol).Value, InStr(1, .Cells(cpyrow, cpycol).Value, " ") - 1)
            cpyrow = cpyrow + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```